# Remove dependency of libapache2-mod-wsgi : Depends: libpython2.6

Tags: python-2.7, apache2, raspberry-pi, mod-wsgi, python-2.6

How to remove the dependency, because it works fine with python2.7 and I don't want python 2.6

I get the following,

```
       sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapache2-mod-wsgi : Depends: libpython2.6 (>= 2.6) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

When trying to correct :

```
    sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libpython2.6 python2.6 python2.6-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python2.6-doc binfmt-support
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython2.6 python2.6 python2.6-minimal
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 105 not upgraded.
Need to get 3415 kB/4824 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I can't install anything because of these, how can I remove the dependency because its working fine without python 2.6 and raspberry pi comes with python 2.7 as default

Edit :
 Question, if I install python 2.6, will python 2.7 co-exist on the raspberry pi?

Comment: For those of you facing the same problem, i did a sudo apt-get -f install and installed all the dependencies. Din't effect my current python programs nor settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get download libapache2-mod-wsgi
sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=libpython2.6,python2.6,python2.6-minimal libapache2-mod-wsgi_2.whatever.deb
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the above does not help.